# Help installing document class for LyX on Mac, unsure on where to start

Tags: lyx, document-classes, thesis

I'm trying to download a document class from a university, and would like to use this for my thesis. However I'm very new to all of this, and so really have little clue on where to start. 
The document class package is located below, I've downloaded the 'ecsdocs.zip' file under the 'installation' heading:
http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/srg/softwaretools/document/templates/

When unzipped, I am able to extract 5 folders, but can't seem to find my the right local texmf directory to place them in. 
I have previously placed the files in usr>local>texlive>texmf-local>tex>latex, but can't seem to find the document class after a lyx reconfigure. Is this even the right folder to place the files in? And once placed into the correct folder, what would be the next steps? Would very much appreciate some detailed guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: Be warned: You should *only* use that if you are attending that institute. Else, use something different. This template is the very basis of [a lot of confusion](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion). I have to say, that this is *not* the fault of the original author.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Johannes_B. I currently attend the University and so all is fine. Although I've seen layouts from other Institutions that are incredibly attractive - very tempting not to use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'd do: create ecsthesis.layout in your thesis folder, make this its contents:

```
#\DeclareLaTeXClass[ecsthesis,book]{ecsthesis}
Format 49
Input stdclass.inc
Input numreport.inc
```

Copy ecsthesis.cls to the same folder.
Create a new file in LyX, save it where these two files are, then in 'Document>Settings>Document Class>Local layout' choose ecsthesis.layout.
I don't know what they have in ecsthesis.cls; if there are any environments not contained in the standard book class you'll either have to use LaTeX insets (Ctrl-L) or add definitions to the layout file.
Some package calls in ecsthesis.cls look a bit outdated, they, for example, use the package subfigure (line 103), I'd replace that with \usepackage{subfig}. I couldn't install the package lstpatch and had to remove the call from ecsthesis.cls.
I'd actually remove everything from line 101 to line 124 - LyX will take care of those packages in case you need them.

LyX>Help>Customization has more on layout files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply PhilipPirrip. When you mention creating the ecsthesis.layout, I don't quite understand how I create this. More specifically where do I type the following mentioned: #\DeclareLaTeXClass[ecsthesis,book]{ecsthesis}
Format 49
Input stdclass.inc
Input numreport.inc?

Apologies for the immense lack of latex knowledge.

Comment: It's a simple ascii text document that you'll name ecsthesis.layout. So, open your text editor, paste the code in and save it as ecsthesis.layout