# Using LaTex class files as layouts in lyx

Tags: lyx, document-classes, lyx-layouts

I would appreciate it if you could please help me with the following issue: I want to write a dissertation in Lyx using university provided LaTex template. The provided class file, dissertation.cls, includes everything, which is based on a report layout. I therefore tried to create a custom layout by something like

```
#% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this
#  \DeclareLaTeXClass[dissertation]{custom made}

# Read the definitions from report.layout

Input report.layout
```

I save it locally, and therefore I can pass it to lyx by selecting it. It seems that, it partially works, because I can compile the thesis, however, spacing and sizing is not the same as what is provided in the class file. I am very confused at this point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome. To use LyX, you need basic knowledge of LaTeX. To use a template you need basic knowledge of LaTeX, to create a LyX Layout you need etended knowledge of LyX layouts. Are you sure it is worth going under all this trouble? Is your universities template even good or would it be better to avoid it since it is badly coded?

Answer (score 0):

Just like in [Help installing document class for LyX on Mac, unsure on where to start](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305410/help-installing-document-class-for-lyx-on-mac-unsure-on-where-to-start/305760#305760), copy the following code to a text file named dissertation.layout

```
#\DeclareLaTeXClass[dissertation,report]{dissertation}
Format 60
Input stdclass.inc
Input numreport.inc
```

and save it in the folder with other thesis files, including dissertation.cls. Then LyX>Document>Settings>Document Class>Local Layout. Choose dissertation.layout. Check LyX>View>Source for the line `\documentclass[english]{dissertation}`.