# Compiling a given Template with given .cls

Tags: journal-publishing

I am trying to use a particular template (given in the 2nd link below). Before I apply this to my own Tex file for my paper, I'd like to learn how to actually compile the given template. I am having trouble with the following steps:

1) For file prepared in AMS-LATEX format: Download the class file “AIMS.cls”
from the following link and place it to the local folder where your tex file
resides.
http://aimsciences.org/journals/tex-sample/AIMS.cls.

Question: The link isn't a download but rather leads to a page with some code. What exactly should I be adding to my folder and how do I do this?

2) For file prepared in AMS-LATEX format: Download the AMS-LATEX
template by clicking the following link and use it as a template to prepare
your tex file.
http://aimsciences.org/journals/tex-sample/Template_1.tex

How do I put these two together to compile the corresponding PDF for the given template? I've never done this before. I've tried (using TeXworks) to (i) compile the Template_1.tex file, (ii) insert the .cls code into a blank template and then compile, and (iii) insert the .cls code into the Template_1.tex code (does it matter where I insert the code?).

In each case, I receive an error.

> ```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9)
> entering extended mode
> (C:/Users/Joseph/Desktop/cls.tex
> LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
> Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
>
> LaTeX Warning: You have requested package `',
>                but the package provides `dcds'.
>
> ! Use of \@ doesn't match its definition.
> \@tempa#1#2\@nil->\edef \@classname{#1}
>
> l.14 \expandafter\@tempa\@currnamestack{}{}{}\@nil
>
> ? "
> ```

I see that part of the problem is that I should not use class *AMS article* nor `\amsart` but use class `\dcds`, so how should I make this change in the template? Is it as simple as replacing every occurrence of "amsart" with "dcds"?

Comment: "amslatex" was the name of a format for a few years before latex2e was released but it has just been "latex" since 1994 so the instructions must be quite old! It just means use latex with that `.cls` file.  (how you use a specific class in lyx I don't know, I don't have lyx).

Comment: you don't actually use the template file in your document that is just an example document to show the format that they require. It is only the AIM.cls file that you use.

Comment: How do I use that file? Do I open a tex file and insert all of that info in the ,cls file? Do I insert the cls code into a new tex file and then insert my tex file (which I obtain from lyx) into the cls. file?

Comment: no a latex document always has first line `\documentclass{....}` and in your case it should be `\documentclass{AIMS}` but as I say I have no idea if it is possible to make lyx write such a file.

Comment: Note: If you'd use the class from the download (which would result in a warning, because the file name differs from the class name), you'd not use class *AMS article* nor `amsart` but class `dcds`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke , how do I use that class? What steps can I take in order to compile the pdf for the download?

Comment: I don't understand what you have done, when you "*paste the code into TeX into Texworks and then incorporate the LyX code into the template*". But [you have to install the class or copy it into the working directory of the main document and create a `layout` file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305760/9057), if you want to use it with LyX. To test the template file either import it into LyX or open it with Texworks after installation of the class (or copying to the same directory as the `Template_1.tex` file). You can run `pdflatex` in Texworks. You will indeed get warnings (see note above).

Answer (score 2):

the file given by the first link should be saved as the file `dcds.cls`.  it can be placed in the same directory as the file you are trying to compile.

in the file you are trying to compile, input this as the first line:

```
\documentclass{dcds}
```

this has nothing to do with the document class `amsart`, so i have removed that from the tags list.